# ZF2 use multiple TableGatway in Single module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I have one problem. I don't know how to use multiple table and join query in zf2.

I'm using service Manager and TableGateway for model. But in this it always use single table. 
How can I use multiple table in single controller or model?

Here I'm using `Module.php` file and configure table gateway. 
When I add another table gateway then it gives me errors.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'factories' => array(
             'User\Model\UserTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
                 $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'UserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
                 return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
     );
 }
```

I need to insert `userItems` in user controller by using `UseritemTable.php` under the `User/Model/UseritemTable`. How I can achieve this?

```
Error message
Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for getUseritemTable
```

Updated Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'factories' => array(
                 'User\Model\UserTable' =>  function($sm) {
                     $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
                     $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
                     return $table;
                 },
                 'UserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                     $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                     $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                     $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
                     return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                 },
                 'User\Model\UseritemTable' =>  function($sm) {
                     $tableGateway = $sm->get('UseritemTableGateway');
                     $table = new UseritemTable($tableGateway);
                     return $table;
                 },
                 'UseritemTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                     $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                     $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                     $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Useritem());
                     return new TableGateway('useritem', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                 },
             ),
         );
     }
```

UserController.php under this userItemAction

```
public function userItemAction()
     {


        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');
        $request = $this->getRequest();

         if ($request->isPost()) {
            $item = new Useritem();
            $data = $request->getPost()->toArray();  
            $form->setData($data);
            if($form->isValid()){
                 $item->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                 $this->getUseritemTable()->saveItem($item); // while saveItem cause error using getUseritemTable()


            }

         }

        return array('form' => $form);

     }
```

Here my code for User\Model\UseritemTable.php

```
namespace User\Model;

 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

 class UseritemTable
 {
     protected $tableGateway;

     public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
     {
         $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
     }

     public function fetchAll()
     {
         $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
         return $resultSet;
     }


     public function saveItem(User $item)
     {
         $this->tableGateway->insert($item);
     }


 }
```

Comment: I need to save user item by using user method in user controller

Comment: Have you added the  `User/Model/UseritemTable` to your factories in `Module.php`?

Comment: yes i have added User/Model/UseritemTable to in factories in Module.php

Comment: this is generating same error

Comment: any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Everything looks ok. Please provide code for `getUseritemTable()` method in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for your support, now my code is executed well.